# Display a message if user is unauthorised to run a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2014

I am new to stored procedures and am just curious how things are done. What I would like to know is how to display a message if a user tries to execute a procedure that he has no rights on ?

From what I can fathom, SQL Server itself takes care of the message. I tried this way (inside a stored procedure) :

```
BEGIN
try
DELETE from MYTABLE
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
        END CATCH;
```

and it makes no difference weather I write this or not. The error is the same. Didnt figure out how to write your own message though ...

Comment: You should be able to catch the error condition thrown by SQL Server. What technology are you using to connect with?

Comment: I am using Delphi (with SDAC components)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a user tries to execute a stored procedure or user-defined function (UDF) that they have not been granted permissions to, either explicitly or implicitly through one or more role memberships, then SQL Server will handle the exception and error message. You cannot set a message within that code as by definition the user is not allowed to execute it to get any error message or error handling that would be inside of it.

If you want a custom message, you need to catch the SQL Exception from the app side (there should be an error code that you can test for indicating "Permission Denied") and then just return your custom message.

Answer (score 0):

There is fix message or say default message display when you try to access unauthorized object.

There is so many security feature comes, like user, role, schema etc. If anything mismatch, you get the error "Could not find stored procedure 'guest.get_procedureName'."

suppose I was created a procedure with default schema(dbo) the name procedure1.

```
exec dbo.procedure1 para1value,'para2value', null,para4value etc.
exec guest.procedure1 para1value,'para2value', null,para4value etc.
```

Now if everything fine, first one give me data to sql side and C# side.
But the second will give me the above error.

**Nothing to handle in the sqlserver side for this type of security, As above your code, try catch is same work as C#, but ideally, it only need when you explicitly want the message from sql return to show directly to ui i.e. custom logic error message, while you run the sp or when mismatch the data etc.**

For the c# point of view, you can get this message in catch, so you can do like.

```
public method    
{
 try
   {
      .....
   }
 catch(Exception ex)
   {
       if (ex.Message.Contains("Could not find"))
         //give any your custom message or throw ex
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
   DoTheThing();
except
   on E:Exception
     ShowMessage("Something Went Wrong! : " + E.Message);
end;
```

This shows a custom message (of sorts) and it also gives you a means to examine the contents of the error via 'E'.

You can also handle more specific exceptions

```
except
    on E:ESomeSpecificException
      // ----
end;
```

--

As others have pointed out - there is no point in trying to catch the error inside the stored proc - the user doesnt have access to it ... by definition